# Extract string before a given substring Python

Tags: python, string, python-re

Here is the sample text.

```
sample_text='Extract text before the last word'
```

Using string split method I can extract substring before 'word'

```
print(sample_text.split('word',1)[0])
```

I am extracting sample_text from a pdf document so there can be following possibilities.

```
sample_text='Extract text before the last w ord'
sample_text='Extract text before the last wo rd'
sample_text='Extract text before the last wor d'
sample_text='Extract text before the last wo r d'
```

Is there a simple way to take these possibilities into account and get the desired output?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression that ignore space :
In your example, with the word "word" that would be the regular expression :

```
"w\s*o\s*r\s*d"
```

Try to split each line in this way :

```
import re

sample_text='Extract text before the last w ord'

re_ignor_space = "w\s*o\s*r\s*d"
sample_text_splitted = re.split(re_ignor_space, sample_text)


desired_string = ''.join(sample_text_splitted[:-1])

print (desired_string)
```

If you do not need the last word just ignore it with slice :

```
desired_string = ''.join(sample_text_splitted[:-1])
```

Output :

```
Extract text before the last
```

Comment: I don't need the last word. Expected output is:- 'Extract text before the last'

Comment: I added another line of code to get you the  'Extract text before the last' Check it out

Comment: Desired string still has 'w ord'

Comment: Okay i change the code and it should do the trick now...check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can split by regex pattern if you want.

```py
import re
pattern = 'w\d?o\d?r\d?d'
print(re.split(pattern, sample_text))
```

Outputs:

```
['Extract text before the last ', '']
```

Comment: It is still printing the entire sample_text.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the pattern, try it now.